# Parse all the data after searching a particular string in an entire dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with around 3000 rows.  I want to search a particular string 'Town Location' in all the rows and then get the index of the row where it appears for the first time so that I can parse all the data below that record.  I have tried idx = df1.index.get_loc('Town Location').idmax() but it didn't work at all.

Comment: `df[df['some_col'] == 'Town Location'].index[0]`?

Comment: Thank you Chris.  The thing is I don't know which column the phrase is in.  This is the reason I can't mention the column name.  Instead,  I want to search it in all the rows.

Comment: `(df == 'Town Location').any(1).index[0]`